# Expandable Listview error inflating class TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I am using material design `tablayout` in my main `activity` where i have `scrollable` tabs and in my very first `fragment` i am using expandable `listview`.

Here is my fragment code

```
public class House_Hold_List_Fragment extends Fragment {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<HouseHoldList_Model> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<HouseHoldList_Model, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.house_hold_list_fragment, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<HouseHoldList_Model>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<HouseHoldList_Model, List<String>>();
        loadModel();
        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void prepareListData(){
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put((HouseHoldList_Model)listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);

    }

    public void loadModel(){
        listDataHeader.add(new HouseHoldList_Model("A"));
        listDataHeader.add(new HouseHoldList_Model("B"));
        listDataHeader.add(new HouseHoldList_Model("C"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                //do something
                Log.e("search clicked","sd");
                return true;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                //do something
                Log.e("search clicked","sd");
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is my model class code where i am just adding name

```
public class HouseHoldList_Model {
    String name;

    public HouseHoldList_Model(){
    }

    public HouseHoldList_Model(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

and here is my **ExpandableListAdapter** class code

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<HouseHoldList_Model> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<HouseHoldList_Model
            , List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<HouseHoldList_Model> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<HouseHoldList_Model, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.house_holld_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.house_hold_list_item);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HouseHoldList_Model model = (HouseHoldList_Model) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.house_hold_list_row, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.house_hold_name);
        lblListHeader.setText(model.name);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

my **house_hold_list_row** is a custom layout for row where i have different fields like name,address etc but at the time i am just displaying only name.
here my logcat.

```
11-13 18:03:05.565 6756-6756/com.zaigham.lhw_diary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.zaigham.lhw_diary, PID: 6756
                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                         at com.zaigham.lhw_diary.HouseHoldList.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:86)
```

Here is my **house_hold_list_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/house_hold_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/hh_count_round"
                android:layout_weight=".5"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/house_hold_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
                    android:text="Muhammad Ramza"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/house_hold_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Main double road g-11"
                    android:textColor="@color/blacktext"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Family Members"
                        android:textColor="@color/blacktext" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/house_hold_fm_number"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/hh_fm_count_round"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/down"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post R.layout.house_hold_list_row

Comment: @ADM i added that

Comment: Error Logs clearly says that you have miss-match in your textview id of row xml file.Kindly check it your self first.

Comment: house_hold_list_row doen't exists in this xml, Probably because of copy paste . Make it right the id of text view

Comment: I checked that @ADM but having same error

Comment: `InflateException` doesn't tell you much. You need to look for the last Exception in the trace.

Comment: Error in getGroupView() method you put the wrong Id for textView . And one more thing you are not using Proper ViewHolder pattern in your adapter . So Use proper [ViewHolder](https://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/) Pattern .and u r good to go .

Comment: @ADM i applied that but having same error OMG

Comment: The Exception is being thrown from the `inflate()` call. There is a problem in the layout. The answers suggesting you rearrange your code aren't going to help with that. We can't tell you what the problem is without the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your textview cannot reference to convertView so take it in your if() condition try below code

```
    if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.house_hold_list_row, null)
          TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.house_hold_name);
        lblListHeader.setText(model.name);
        }
```

Comment: may be your condition not working as you want so first check 'if' condition working proper or not, better way try with removing 'if' condition....

Comment: I checked that OMI

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work
    @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            HouseHoldList_Model model = (HouseHoldList_Model) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.house_hold_list_row, null);
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.house_hold_name);
            }

            lblListHeader.setText(model.name);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Why will that work? How does it fix the `InflateException` that's being thrown in the `inflate()` call? That won't even compile anyway, since `lblListHeader` is out of scope outside of the `if` block.